# ¿Como usar un solo Escuchas para controlar dos listas?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo  Jlist lista y Jlist lista2 tengo un método escuchas donde tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public void ecuchas() {
        lista.addListSelectionListener(new Esc_lista());
        lista2.addListSelectionListener(new Esc_lista());
    }
```

lo que quiero hacer en el método escuchas es solamente tener un .addListSelectionListener(new Esc_lista()); pero que funcione para las dos listas la verdad no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo por favor espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Pues agrega en el método `ecuchas` un parámetro de tipo `JList` y luego adentro del método quedaría una única línea de código.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente debes crear un solo listener el cual configuraras para ambas listas, ejemplo:

```
public void ecuchas() {

    Esc_lista escucha = new Esc_lista();

    lista.addListSelectionListener(escucha);
    lista2.addListSelectionListener(escucha);

}
```